# How do I get my code to reset or reinitialize after it's been run and how can I reset my loop for my password prompt in java?

Tags: java

I have a Java project that I am working for the school, and I am a beginner. For school, I have to create an authentication program, and for the most part, I figured it out on my own. However, I am having an issue implementing a three failed attempts, and you're locked out kind of thing. All while loops and if statements just mess up the program. I also need help re-initializing the program once it brings up the prompt of a correct user input. The main method is in another class but essentially all it does is it only asks the user for the username, and then it sends it to this class while this class does all the work. It needs to be polished as well, so there is a lot of unnecessary code that I will remove once I get the program running how I like.

```
package authenticationsystem;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class UserInfo {
private Scanner x;
private Scanner z;
private String user;
private String pass;
private String role;
private String hash;
private boolean trip = false;

public void userName(String name) throws Exception {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userLine, hashCode, password="", userPass, roleFile;
    int quotes, quotes2, lineLength, usernameLength, hashLength;
    int lineNumber = 0, i = 0;

    user = name;

    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("src\\authenticationsystem\\credentials.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("could not find file");
    }

    while(x.hasNextLine()) {
        userLine = x.nextLine();
        if (userLine.contains(user)) {

            usernameLength = user.length();
            lineLength = userLine.length();
            quotes = userLine.indexOf('\"');
            quotes2 = userLine.lastIndexOf('\"');

            //password = userLine.substring((quotes + 1), quotes2);

            //System.out.println(password);
            System.out.println(usernameLength + " " + lineLength);
            System.out.println("Please enter your password");
            userPass = scnr.nextLine();

            //userPass = password;
            hashCode = userLine.substring((usernameLength + 1), (usernameLength + 32));
            roleFile = userLine.substring((quotes2 + 1), lineLength);
            setPassword(userPass);
            setHashCode(hashCode, roleFile);
            user = userLine.substring(0, usernameLength);
            }
        else if (user.equals("Exit") || user.equals("exit")) {
            System.exit(i);
        }
        lineNumber++;    
        }      
}
String getName() {
    return user;
}
public void setPassword(String passW) throws Exception {
    pass = passW;

    String original = passW;  //Replace "password" with the actual password inputted by the user
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(original.getBytes());
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (byte b : digest) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    }

    hash = sb.toString();        
}
public String getPassword() {
    return pass;
}
public void setHashCode(String hashC, String roleF) {
    AuthenticationSystem mane = new AuthenticationSystem();
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (hash.contains(hashC)) {
        if (roleF.contains("admin") || roleF.contains("Admin")) {
        try{
            z = new Scanner(new File("src\\authenticationsystem\\admin.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
        while(z.hasNext()) {
            String a = z.nextLine();
            String b = z.nextLine();
            String c = z.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c);
        }
        role = roleF;
    }
    else if (roleF.contains("veterinarian") || roleF.contains("Veterinarian")) {
        try{
            z = new Scanner(new File("src\\authenticationsystem\\veterinarian.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
        while(z.hasNext()) {
            String a = z.nextLine();
            String b = z.nextLine();
            String c = z.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c);
        }
        role = roleF;
    }
    else if (roleF.contains("zookeeper") || roleF.contains("Zookeeper")) {
        try{
            z = new Scanner(new File("src\\authenticationsystem\\zookeeper.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("could not find file");
        }
        while(z.hasNext()) {
            String a = z.nextLine();
            String b = z.nextLine();
            String c = z.nextLine();

            System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", a, b, c);
        }
        role = roleF;
    }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid hash codes.");
    }
}
public String getHashCode() {
    return hash;
}
public void closeFile () {
    x.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Your source code has some serious **non logical** problems, that make debugging harder than necessary. If you clean it up first then your problem might solve itself. The scanners `x` and `z` for example could receive a more meaningful name and could probably stay in their respective function scope; no need for them to be class members, right?

Comment: You don't need to declare all variables upfront. It's better style to keep them in the smallest scope possibly: The variables `userLine, lineLength, quotes` and `quotes2` are never used outside of the while loop; declare them inside.

Comment: Also consider to not use the Scanners `x` and `z` outside of the try catch blocks. If the files are not found, then these variable are never initialized (= null) -> `x.hasNext()` throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: I have made some modifications with the suggestions you recommended. I finally got the code to give up after 3 tries but I am still trying to figure out how to get the code to reset once the role file has been obtained. I'm having trouble doing that but no dice yet.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you do a throw exception you don't need to try catch it. practically the throws exception works as a "i'll let another method to handle my exception".

Regarding on how you want to loop to prompt for the password you might want to use a switch case and use a counter variable to do the tries for it, so lets say it would be something like this:

```
int counter = 0; 
do{
switch(counter){
case 1: 
askForPass();
counter++;
break;
.
.
.
case 3:
askForPass();
counter++;
myBool = true; 
}while(myBool == false);
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: I tried out the code you gave but did not know how to modify it correctly. I did however figure out how to get the program to cut off after 3 unsuccessful tries. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: yeah! good thing you figured out on your own. That is what makes a programmer good.